# FullCalendar V4 - How to account for shorter months in a recurring event series?

Tags: recurring-events, rrule, fullcalendar-4

I'm using [FullCalendar v4-alpha-3](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4) with the [RRule plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/rrule-plugin) to generate recurring events. It works as expected with only one problem: how do I modify a recurring event to account for months with fewer days than the starting month in a series?

For example, if the first monthly occurrence happens on January 29, 2019; the event will be repeated on the 29th of all subsequent months except in February since it only has 28 days (leap years excluded).

I've tried resetting `dtstart` to the first day of the following month. It works, except the event is no longer recursive.

Here's a stripped down snippet of my setup:

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ rrulePlugin ],
  events: [
    {
      rrule: 'DTSTART:20190129 RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20200130;COUNT=13;BYMONTHDAY=29'
    }
  ],
  eventRender: function(info) {
    ...

    // reset start date to the first day of the following month 
    // if current month has fewer days than base month

    let start = event.start;
    let day = start.getDate();            

    let now = new Date();
    let currentMonth = now.getMonth();     
    let currentYear = now.getFullYear();
    let daysInCurrent = getDaysInMonth(currentMonth + 1, currentYear);

    let nextStart = start;
    if (day > daysInCurrent) {
        nextStart = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 1);    
        event.setStart(nextStart);   
        event.setEnd(null);                     
    } 
  }
});
```

I'd appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite the solution I hoped for, but RRule's `bysetpos` property seems to offer the next best alternative as it allows for a fallback date in case the one specified doesn't exist.

For example, the following would generate an occurrence on the 30th of every month; or the last day of the month if the 30th doesn’t exist:

`FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=28,29,30;BYSETPOS=-1`.

Sourced from: https://icalevents.com/2555-paydays-last-working-days-and-why-bysetpos-is-useful/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but maybe this will be usefull for someone:

I'm using momentjs library

```
monthly:

let endofmonth = moment('2020-02-29', "YYYY-MM-DD").endOf('month').format('DD');
let curday = moment('2020-02-29, "YYYY-MM-DD").format('DD');
single_event.title = title;
single_event.rrule = {};
single_event.rrule.freq = 'monthly';
single_event.rrule.dtstart = start_date;
single_event.rrule.interval = reminder_interval;
single_event.rrule.count = reminder_count;

if(endofmonth == curday){
    // Checking if given day of the month is last
    single_event.rrule.byweekday = ['mo','tu','we','th','fr','sa','su'];
    single_event.rrule.bysetpos = -1;
}
else{
    single_event.rrule.bymonthday = parseInt(curday);
}

calendar_events.push(single_event);

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    ...
    events: calendar_events
});



yearly:

single_event.title = title;
single_event.rrule = {};
single_event.rrule.dtstart = start_date;
single_event.rrule.count = parseInt(reminder_count);

if(endofmonth == curday){
    // Checking if given day of the month is last
    single_event.rrule.freq = 'monthly'; // Will work as yearly if interval is 12
    single_event.rrule.interval = parseInt(reminder_interval)*12;
    single_event.rrule.bymonthday = [28,29,30,31];
    single_event.rrule.bysetpos = -1;
}
else{
    single_event.rrule.freq = 'yearly';
    single_event.rrule.bymonthday = parseInt(curday);
}

calendar_events.push(single_event);

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    ...
    events: calendar_events
});
```